# Load new page directly if user is already logged in into facebook

Tags: php, ajax, facebook

On index.php I perform facebook login, If not logged in ask user to perform login. 
If already logged in, it should automtically redirect to `url.php`.

I have made my try but dont know, it always needs to perform button click event to load url.php though user is already logged in.

This function is called by button click event. I called it on page load event, but no luck.

My entire source code is here: http://codetidy.com/6994/
I need to use inline css due to some reason in above code.

```
 function CallAfterLogin(data,callback){
      //alert("CallafterLogin3");
      FB.login(function(response) {
        //---
        if (response.status === "connected")
        {
          LodingAnimate();

          FB.api('/me?fields=movies,email,name', function(mydata) {
            console.log(mydata.email);
          // console.log(mydata.id); 
           var myid=mydata.id;
           var name=mydata.name;
           //alert(name);
           var email=mydata.email;

              var json = JSON.stringify(mydata.movies.data);
              var a = JSON.parse(json);

              $.post('movies_db.php',{'myd':a, name: name, email: email, myid:myid}, function(data) 
                     {
                       $.ajax({
                         url:'url.php'
                         ,async:     true
                         ,type : 'POST'
                         ,cache:     false
                         ,data : 'myid=' + myid
                         ,dataType:  'html'
                         ,success:   function(data){
                           $('body').html(data);
                           FB.XFBML.parse();
                         }
                       }
                             );

                     }
```

Comment: I think it has the same idea as Your previous question, because if we if the user already has authenticated your app and `has a-live session (unexpired cookie)` We will print out user ID... 
But here I think your case different, What you want is to know whether the user is logged into Facebook account (http://www.facebook.com), right?

Comment: @AdamZapp: My intension is something different. Like if you have selected remember password then when you open facebook it does not show you login page.
In the same way I have first page where user's login action takes place. If user has already authenticated my app and already logged into fb, then he should not be asked to perform login, and 2nd page i.e. `url.php ` should be loaded. But in my case it always show fist page where login action takes place. Never redirect to new page though user is already logged in.

Comment: [FB.getLoginStatus](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/) will help you with this!